# Windows 8.1 Refresh/Recovery

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

I recently did an update of my machine from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. The update process did not show any errors or warnings and by the time it finished I was under the impression that everything went smooth.

Due to some issues I need to refresh my PC.

Once I clicked Refresh My PC the verification process started and indeed it told my that some system files are missing.

[image]

The Windows 8.0 install media does not work. Since I upgraded from the Store, I don't have the Windows 8.1 media.

I tried creating the Windows 8.1 media [as instructed here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media). It downloads the `WindowsSetupBox.exe` program, and prompts for a product key. I entered my Windows 8 product key, but it does not work.

[image]

How can I refresh my 8.1 machine? As a recap my situation is I was a Windows 8 owner and upgraded to Windows Blue. Because I upgraded from the Windows Store, I don't have an 8.1 product key or the installation media.

Answer (score 3):

The article [HOW TO: Download Windows 8.1 ISO Image](http://www.ahemahem.com/download-windows-8-1-iso-image-final/776/) describes how one can download
the Windows 8.1 ISO using the Windows 8 serial. Windows will detect this ISO when you initiate a refresh, or you can attempt to repair
your installation via a [Repair Install](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html).

This operation is dangerous and can leave you with a crippled installation.
Before starting, backup all your data and create a system restore point, just in case.
Create also a backup of all your drivers, using for example [Driver Magician Lite](http://www.drivermagician.com/Lite.htm).
Copy the backups elsewhere than on your system disk.

Even better, create a system image of your **entire** hard disk using for example
[AOMEI Backupper](http://www.aomeitech.com/). In case of serious problems, you may need
to [Create an AOMEI Bootable CD or USB Flash Drive](http://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)

The procedure follows :

1. Download the setups for **both** Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 from
   [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only).
2. Execute `Windows8-Setup.exe`. Enter your Windows 8 serial key and press
   `Next` whenever it asks. Once the download begins,
   pause it and close the window using the standard X close button.
3. Execute `WindowsSetupBox.exe` now. The download will restart from scratch and you’ll have the Windows 8.1 ISO image instead of the Windows 8 ISO image

You could follow this with the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html)
to write the ISO to USB (works also for Windows 8) from which to boot.

Comment: This seems to be working. I just want to add that it wasn't clear when to cancel out. The screen immediately following [this one](http://i.imgur.com/MTWsJjv.png) said something like "Getting things ready" and had an option to pause. I paused it and closed the window using the standard `X` close button.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "Refresh" option doesn't work, you might have to reboot your computer into the UEFI's troubleshooter. Try going through [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-do-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-how-to-downgrade-back-to-windows-8/) first, but if that doesn't work, the procedure below may help.

Most computers I've used have a recovery partition which is accessed by loading the troubleshooter at boot. To get there, you will need to shutdown completely (which can either be done by choosing "Restart," typing "shutdown /s /f /t 0" at the command prompt, or removing all power). After that, you should see something briefly upon boot that says, "Press  for System Information..." or a similar message. If not, the buttons are likely F1, F2, F12, or ESC. Hopefully one of those brings you to some more options to revert to Windows 8.

Comment: I don't want to revert to 8. Thats the whole issue. I just need to fix my Windows 8.1 installation.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood. Given that, I'm not entirely sure how to repair it without reverting to Windows 8, then re-upgrading to 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same trouble as you have. I had pre-installed OEM windows 8.1. But then I used my university key to make it a licensed windows 8. When I wanted to refresh my PC it also prompted me to insert a media (and had none). 
I searched so i found this:

1. Open command prompt in administrator mode (by right clicking the windows logo on the bottom left of the screen.
2. mkdir C:\RefreshImage and hit Enter.
3. recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage and hit Enter. (This thing will take some time(for me it took 6 hours). Also make sure you have around 40-50 GB free space.

And then try to refresh your PC again. It worked for me.

for further details follow this post : http://www.gizmag.com/how-to-windows-8-pc-refresh-reset/32801/

I hope it helps.